# Why does my diagonal matrix calculator not return the total?

Tags: ruby

My method should take an array of subarrays, find the sum of the first value of the first array, the second value of the second array, the third value of the third array, and so on. Some examples of inputs and expected results are as follows:

```
exampleArray = [
  [1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1]
]
diagonalSum(exampleArray) # => 4

exampleArray = [
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
]
diagonalSum(exampleArray) # => 5
```

I wrote this:

```
def diagonalSum(matrix)
  total = 0
  counter = 0
  while matrix.length <= counter + 1 do
    total += matrix[counter][counter]
    counter += 1
  end 
  total
end
```

and it returns `0`.

Comment: Hint: Will the length be `<= 0` at the start of the loop?

Comment: `while matrix.length <= counter+1 do` will never proceed inside the loop.

Comment: thank you tadman reversing that operator that fixed everything!

Comment: A more Ruby-like way of writing your method is `def diagonal_sum(matrix); matrix.each_index.reduce(0) { |tot, counter| tot + matrix[counter][counter] }; end; diagonal_sum [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] #=> 15 (1+5+9)`.

Comment: One Ruby convention is to use "snake case" for names of variables and methods: lowercase letters, underscores and (except for the first character) digits, and in the case of methods, possibly "!" or "?" as the last character.  You don't have to follow the convention, but 99%+ of Rubiests do.

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to convert the array to a matrix and apply [Matrix#trace](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-trace).

```
require 'matrix'

arr = [[1, 0, 0, 7],
       [0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 0],
       [8, 0, 0, 4]]

Matrix[*arr].trace
  #=> 10
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you provide, in which the input is an array of arrays, the first advice I could give you is that in Ruby you must avoid using `for/while` loops and make use of iterators such as `each/each_with_index` instead (based on this [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) and the suggestions of @tadman and @Yu Hao).

The [each with index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each_with_index) iterator takes a Ruby block with the current array of the iteration along with its index position, so you don't need to define your own index variable and update it in every iteration.

Applying this to your code will result in the following:

```
def diagonal_sum(matrix)
  total = 0
  matrix.each_with_index do |row, index|
    total+=row[index]
  end
  total
end
```

Also note that the convention in Ruby is to write variable and method names in snake_case (according to the previous style guide).